# Submitted comment edit in textarea then save

Tags: php, forms, report

SO, I am working on a short script that takes a user's "bug report" and saves it. Showing the comment at the bottom of the page with an Edit button for editing. I want for that button to take the user to another page with a textarea, their comment would be editable here and a Save button to save their report. I am not sure how to link to the exact comment the user would upload.
Like this: 
[image: report]

[image: edit]

This is what I have so far:

## Bug Reports

```
<form method="POST" action="Bugs.php">
  <p>Bug Name <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
   Hardware Type <input type="text" name="hw" /><br />
   OS <input type="text" name="os" /> <br />
   Frequency of Occurence <input type="text" name="freq" /></p>
  <p>Proposed Solutions<br />
  <textarea name="sol" rows="6" cols="100"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create New Bug Report" /></p>
</form>

<?php 



 $Dir = "comments";

 if (is_dir($Dir)) {
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $String = "Unknown Visitor";
    }
    else 
        $String = stripslashes($_POST['name']) . "|";
        $String .= stripslashes($_POST['hw']) . "|";
        $String .= stripslashes($_POST['os']) . "|";
        $String .= stripslashes($_POST['freq']) . "|";
        $String .= stripslashes($_POST['sol']);
        $CurrentTime = microtime();
        $TimeArray = explode(" ", $CurrentTime);
        $TimeStamp = (float)$TimeArray[1] + (float)$TimeArray[0];
        /* File name is " Comment.seconds.microseconds.txt" */
        $SaveFileName = "$Dir/Comment.$TimeStamp.txt";
            if (file_put_contents($SaveFileName, $String)>0)
                echo "File \"" . htmlentities($SaveFileName) . "\" successfully saved.<br />\n";
            else
                echo "There was an error writing \"" . htmlentities($SaveFileName) . "\".<br />\n";
    }
 }

if (is_dir($Dir)) {    //show submitted reports on page
$CommentFiles = scandir($Dir);
foreach ($CommentFiles as $FileName) {
    if (($FileName != ".") && ($FileName != "..")) {
        echo "From <strong>$FileName</strong><br />";
        echo "<pre>\n";
        $Comment = file_get_contents($Dir . "/" . $FileName);
        echo $Comment . "<a href=edit.php>Edit</a>";
        echo "</pre>";
        echo "<hr />";
    }
  }
}



?>
```

Comment: i think you really need to think about your code structure, if you are not going to insert data to a SQL server, you have to assign an id to each bug report that you're writing to your file(s) and keep those id's in another file so you can detect them, after that you can use that id to do your stuff, also keep in mind that only the user that sent that bug report should be able to edit it

Comment: yes sorry for the sloppiness I'm new to php and very much in the process of learning(I hear Gosselin isn't the best author), as always, if you have any good resources to learn PHP I will gladly appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to put all this into a database it would be much easier.

However.. when you foreach all the comments in the folder add a $_GET variable with the file name like this:

```
echo $Comment . "<a href=edit.php?com_id=" . urlencode($Filename) . ">Edit</a>";
```

Then with edit section you can call urldecode($_GET['com_id']) to access the file name and edit the comment.